# Comparing growth rate of exponential function?

Tags: algorithm, function, big-o, time-complexity, asymptotic-complexity

Suppose we have two functions f(n) = 2<sup>2<sup>n+1</sup></sup> and g(n)=2<sup>2<sup>n</sup></sup>. I want to compare their growth rates of these two functions using two different methods.

### Method One: Take the Ratio

Let's define t(n) = f(n) / g(n). Then

> t(n) = f(n) / g(n)
>
> = 2<sup>2<sup>n+1</sup></sup> / 2<sup>2<sup>n</sup></sup>
>
> = 2<sup>2<sup>n + 1</sup> - 2<sup>n</sup></sup>
>
> = 2<sup>2<sup>n</sup></sup>

So we'll assume that f(n) grows much faster than g(n).

### Method Two: Use Logarithms

As before, let t(n) = f(n) / g(n). Now, let's take log base two of both sides:

> lg t(n) = lg (f(n) / g(n))
>
> = lg (2<sup>2<sup>n+1</sup></sup> / 2<sup>2<sup>n</sup></sup>)
>
> = lg 2<sup>2<sup>n+1</sup></sup> - lg 2<sup>2<sup>n</sup></sup>)
>
> = 2<sup>n+1</sup> - 2<sup>n</sup>

Now, let's take the log base two of both sides:

> lg lg t(n) = (n + 1) lg 2 / n lg 2
>
> = (n + 1) / n

Ignoring constant term, we get lg lg t(n) = 1, which is a constant, so f(n) and g(n) should have the same growth rate.

Why am I getting the wrong answer using Method Two ?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about mathematics.

Comment: You assume `a/b=(log a)/(log b)` which is generally wrong.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about maths.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your error is assuming the following:

> If log log f(x) / log log g(x) is a constant, then f(x) = Θ(g(x)).

Here's an easy counterexample to this. Let f(x) = x<sup>2</sup> and g(x) = x. Then

> log log f(x) = log log x<sup>2</sup> = log (2 log x) = log 2 + log log x

and

> log log g(x) = log log x

Here, log log f(x) and log log g(x) differ just by a constant (namely, log 2), but clearly it's not true that f(x) and g(x) grow at the same rates. In other words, it's not safe to ignore constants after taking the logs of the growth rates of two functions.

There's a second error in your logic. If you compute f(n) / g(n), you get

> 2<sup>2<sup>n + 1</sup></sup> / 2<sup>2<sup>n</sup></sup>
>
> = 2<sup>2<sup>n+1</sup> - 2<sup>n</sup></sup>
>
> = 2<sup>2<sup>n</sup></sup>

If you take the log of this twice, you get

> lg lg 2<sup>2<sup>n</sup></sup>
>
> = lg 2<sup>n</sup>
>
> = n

So it's not even true that the log log of the ratio is (n + 1) / n; instead, it's n, which still tends onward toward infinity. This would also tell you that f(n) grows much more rapidly than g(n).

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 2):

Where you went wrong: "ignoring the constant term".

t(n) = (n+1)/n = n/n + 1/n = 1 + 1/n > 1

Comment: 1 + 1/n is bounded above by the constant 2, though.

Comment: @Scott Hunter Yeah you are right. I got it where I made mistake